# Origin of the phrase "Mustard on the beat"?

Tags: rap, etymology

I have realized that in many rap songs by many different artists use the phrase, "mustard on the beat" at the begging of their rap.

Where did this originate? Why do many different DJs and rappers use this?

In my research, I have found this:

From [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DJ_Mustard):

> Dijon Isaiah McFarlane (born June 5, 1990), professionally known as DJ Mustard...
>
> Almost all of his productions begin or end with the tag "Mustard on the beat, hoe!"

But where and why do other rappers, such as 2-Chainz, Kid Ink, and YG just to name a few, use this phrase? What's significant about it's origin? Why him?

Comment: @jayfrizzle is right. Basically, if you hear `[anything] on the beat` you can assume it's produced by that producer. Some producers also like to put the same (robot) voice into all their beats, just another proof of repetition in modern music.

I recommend looking up the song on genius.com. It's usually a good place to find more information about the song itself and the lyrics.
For example: On genius.com, for the song [*I'm Good* by *YG*](http://genius.com/Yg-im-good-lyrics) it says the Producer is DJ Mustard.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Mustard on the beat" usually refers to the fact that the beat (the instrumental track to which the artist is rapping over) was constructed and produced by DJ Mustard. They are literally saying "This beat was made by DJ Mustard"

Answer (score 2):

It IS the signature branding drop for DJ MUSTARD, who produces these beats... 
BUT HOWEVER, it is actually the voice sample of rapper Y.G, who says it near the end of his "I'm Good" song, 2011.

http://youtu.be/waX2fj0rk2g?t=2m29s

Answer (score 1):

"Put mustard on it" is a phrase usually used in sports, which refers to someone "[adding velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_baseball_(M)#mustard)" to a pitch or throw.

Therefore, it stands to reason that "Mustard on the beat" relates to the emphasis (added velocity) on the downbeat in a song.

Answer (score 0):

It originally comes from the song “I’m Good” by YG. If you listen, there’s a part in the middle of his song when he adlibs, saying the now famous line.